# Avoiding merge conflicts with .vcxproj* files

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, visual-c++

My team is using Visual Studio for a C++ projects, and whenever we both add new files on our branches, we get these obnoxious merge conflicts in the .vcxproj and .vcxproj.filter files. All that happens is one new entry is added to each file for each file, but git doesn't seem to like this and thinks the entire file has changed. So the merge conflicts end up taking a good 5-10 minutes to resolve. Repeating this every time we have to merge has gotten fairly annoying.

Is there any way to avoid these conflicts, other than just not adding new files?

Comment: If you are able to use a tool to generate the .vcxproj files based on higher level configuration information, you can avoid the merge hassles. We use python scripts and qmake to generate .vcxproj files base on project configuration specified using files and directories.

Comment: Consider use of wildcards, e.g. `<ClCompile Include="$(OurSourceDirectory)\*.cpp" />`. Adding a file becomes as simple as creating the file in the directory and reloading the project.  If you don't want to do this, then at least keep items in alphabetical order in the project file.  This should make merges straightforward.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, is there a setting to change for that? Currently, VS is adding these entries automatically. I'm not a frequent VS user.

Comment: The IDE doesn't support this.  You have to manually edit the vcxproj file to do this.